# Capistrano 3: use short `cap deploy` to deploy on production by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm curious how to configure **capistrano 3** with short `cap deploy` command to deploy on production by default instead of full `cap production deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your deploy.rb:

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :stages, ["dev", "production"]
set :default_stage, "production"
```

Then run:

```
cap deploy
```

Comment: I use Capistrano 3. Unfortunately, there are no such settings as above. And you don't need to require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'.

Answer (score 0):

In your Capfile add this at the bottom

```
invoke :beta
```

This will call the beta stage and make it the default.

I'm not shure this is the correct way, but it seems to work :)